# Can current still be (alternatively) measured with a blown multimeter fuse?

Tags: voltage, current, current-measurement, multimeter, voltage-measurement

With a blown fuse in a multimeter, is it still possible to measure current of a device by somehow measuring voltage and resistance?

If so, how would this work? Do specific probing/measuring points matter?

Comment: Why not just replace the fuse?

Comment: It's en route, but I'm curious for alternatives in the meantime (and likewise curious as a matter of principle).

Comment: If you know what blew the fuse (i.e. it's not an internal problem of the meter), and you promise the multimeter not to do it again, you can get away with shorting the fuse clips with a piece of wire _temporarily_.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, provided that:

1) The fuse blown only affects the current measuring function and not the voltage (and if needed, resistance) measuring circuits of the meter.

2) You have a small value resistor of sufficient power rating which you can insert into the circuit to be measured, and either know it's value by specification or can measure it with desired accuracy using the resistance function.

3) The circuit will still function, and in a representative way, when subject to the voltage drop produced by the instantaneous current through the sense resistor inserted to facilitate the measurement.

If all these conditions are true, the current is the voltage drop measured across the resistor divided by the value of the resistor.

Appropriate sizing of the resistor will depend on the current you expect to measure and the tolerance of the circuit under test to this current-dependent voltage drop.

Comment: I would argue that this is often a BETTER option than using the current range on the meter even if it's not broken. It means *you* get to control the tradeoff between accuracy and burden voltage. It means you don't have things like test leads and fuses in the current path which add burden voltage without contributing to the measurement accuracy. Finally it means that you can disconnect the meter to measure something else without interrupting the current.

Answer (score 1):

I concur Chris's answer. I teach this to my automotive students so they have an alternative method to measure current with their voltmeters.

Use a very low resistance resistors in parallel to increase the wattage.

Example: Two 1-Ohm, five Watt resistors in parallel will make a 1/2 Ohm, 10 Watt resistor.

Comment: in parallel? won't that act like a short with the very low resistor?

Comment: @alex for a current meter a short across a small resistor is how it is measured. A small value means a small voltage compared to the current which minimizes the effect of the resistive heating and doesn't greatly affect the circuit being measured. It's called a shunt resistor.